# Mootools get first value from each

Tags: php, ajax, json, mootools

I have one array images from Json:

```
images=JSON.decode(images);
```

This is the array value :

```
[
    {
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "name": "loc commerciale.jpg"
    },
    {
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "name": "foto2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "name": "foto 1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "name": "a01.jpg"
    }
]
```

I get the value from name :

```
images.each(function(image){                
    alert(image.name);
});
```

I need to get only the first value name

Like php :

```
$images = (array) json_decode($row->images);
$first = true;
foreach ($images as $k => $image) {
    if ($first)
    {
        $firstimage= $image->name;
        $first = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with: `var firstImageName = images[0].name;`?

Comment: I need to get the first value name in mootools like a php

Comment: I could ask the same about your php code too. To rephrase my question: why do you want to take first element in loop?

Comment: Sorry ok the first way

Comment: so use what PLB suggested : `images[0]` is the first image.

Comment: he may not have a first element, this will create a reference error.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (images[0].length){
    var firstImageName = images[0].name;
}
```